# Rails - set attribute of parent based on child id after both created together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model `user_item` with an attribute called `:primary_image_id`.  A `user_item` `has_many` `user_item_images`.  The purpose of the `primary_image_id` is to set it equal to the id of one of the `user_item_images` so then I can use logic so that object can't be deleted by the user in the view.

A `user_item` should never exist without this attribute set, or at least exist for a couple seconds until the attribute is set.  In my form the `user_item` is created along with `user_item_images`.

It seems like the `user_item_image.id` is only set after create.  I tried doing an `after_create` callback on the `user_item`

```
  def set_primary_image_id
    self.primary_image_id = self.user_item_images.first.id
  end
```

but it didn't seem to work, I'm guessing because the child wan't created and so didn't have an id.

I guess I could do an `after_create` callback on the `user_item_image` model, something like:

```
def set_user_item_primary_image_id
  user_item = self.user_item
  user_item.primary_image_id = user_item.user_item_images.first.id
end
```

but this seems like overkill because it really shouldn't be done every time a `user_item_image` is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `after_create`s may be properly setting the field, but they're not writing anything to the database. Try:

```
update_attributes(primary_image_id: user_item_images.first.id)
```

If the `user_item_images` exist before you create the `user_item`, you could also set the field in a `before_create`, avoiding the need for a second write query. Whatever you do, sprinkle some prints or drop into a debugger to check whether you have no data vs. are not writing it.

If you're creating everything all at once using `build`, all objects will be created and have IDs before `UserItem#set_user_item_primary_image_id` runs, so this will work just fine:

```
ui = UserItem.new(params[:user_item])
image = ui.user_item_images.build(params[:user_item_image])
ui.save # Creates UserItem, creates UserItemImage, assigns primary_image_id
```

To make that even cleaner, check out [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: I have a nested form that creates a `user_item` as well as `user_item_images` that belong_to the `user_item` on submit.  If I put the `after_create` on the `user_item` model, would this happen after the whole transaction or would it happen before the `user_items` children exist?

Comment: Using `build`, the `after_create` will run once everything has the IDs you need.